# My lambda reads JSON file from S3 bucket and it will ingest data into Redshift table. But I have encountered a 'Spectrum Scan Error'

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

My lambda reads JSON file from S3 bucket and it will ingest data into Redshift table. But I have encountered the below error:

```
[INFO]  2020-09-20T23:01:10.809Z    00f2985a-b405-48be-8d12-149c0b739671    Did not connect: Spectrum Scan Error
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Spectrum Scan Error
  code:      15001
  context:   Error: HTTP response error code: 403 Message: AccessDenied Access Denied
x-amz-request-id: 454E99A6199E5C8C
x-amz-id-2: YKwJSH8BwrBr5xQAldKXdMSQ6ii2bRbUCPFAw1muHScLBt+2RcczeQq/M3HMYOIeUCLHCGebrkk=
Ion/JSON Stream error while opening buffer: Read error. In 
  query:     11606404
  location:  dory_util.cpp:941
  process:   fetchtask_thread [pid=5446]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by changing the policy, and it's working. Thanks for those answered.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are able to read S3 contents but not able to write data to Redshift. As the error message says "403" (forbidden) it is a client-side error. So you need to give IAM permission to that specific user/role to write to Redshift.

There is another question which might be again helpful for you [InternalError_: Spectrum Scan Error. S3 to Redshift copy command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60921001/internalerror-spectrum-scan-error-s3-to-redshift-copy-command)

Thanks