# Redshift COPY command: Spectrum Scan Error - Different parquet types for same column

Tags: pandas, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, parquet

I am copying multiple parquet files from s3 to redshift in parallel using the copy command. The parquet files are created using pandas as part of a python ETL script.

An `integer` column (accountID) on the source database can contain nulls, and if it does it is therefore converted to parquet type `double` during the ETL run (pandas forces an array of integers with any missing values to become floating point).

The accountID column in some files might be null, and other files won't be null. Therefore some column types will be `double` and some `int64`

If I set my redshift column is `int8`, file2 loads but file1 produces this error:

> Spectrum Scan Error. File file1.parquet.gz  has an incompatible Parquet
> schema for column accountid. Column type: `BIGINT`, Parquet
> schema:\noptional `double` AccountID [i:7 d:1 r:0]

When I change the column to `float` and rerun the command, file1 loads but file2 fails with this error:

> Spectrum Scan Error. File file2.parquet.gz  has an incompatible Parquet
> schema for column accountid. Column type: `DOUBLE`, Parquet
> schema:\noptional `int64` AccountID [i:7 d:1 r:0]

I have read other SO [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60921001/internalerror-spectrum-scan-error-s3-to-redshift-copy-command) relating to Spectrum Scan Error that have helped me get this far.

Is there a datatype I can use in redshift that will allow for parquet types `int` and `double` to be inserted?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tell pandas to use the dtype `Int64`, it's a NULLable integer class, as opposed to the primitive integer.  Also, if you are creating several parquet files (partitioned) one at a time, you may find each file has different dtypes; one file with NAs may use float and another file with no NAs may use integer. In such cases you need to set the column types yourself, rather than relying on default implicit types.

Comment: I've watched you make several edits. I'm convinced you simply need to use the correct dtype (`Int64`) to avoid an integer column sometimes being implicitly coerced to float. Docs : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes it looks like I need to set the column types. Cheers